# How to get a BrowserWindow from a WebContents in electron?

Tags: electron

This is probably stairing me in the face but given a `WebContents` how do I find the corresponding `BrowserWindow`?

Of the top of my head I can do

```
const windows = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
const ndx = windows.indexOf(someWebContents);
const window = windows[ndx];
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: What's with [`remote.getCurrentWindow()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#remotegetcurrentwindow)?

Comment: that would assume the current window corresponds to the webContents in question. it's not in my case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) static method seems to be the most straightforward way:

> [BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(webContents)](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#browserwindowfromwebcontentswebcontents)
>
> Returns BrowserWindow - The window that owns the given webContents.